# Writing a state value into the browser console using React-Native

Tags: reactjs, console, react-native

I need to write a `TextInput` value into the browser console, but when I try to do this I get an error as on the below screenshot or it gets erased automatically when I type in the username into `TextInput`.

*Error:*

[image].

*My code:*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {TextInput , Button , View } from 'react-native';

export default class Profile extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
      this.state = {
        text:''
      }
    }
  handleChangeText = (typedText) => {
    this.setState({text:typedText});
    console.log(this.state.text);
  }
  render() {
    return (
            <View> 
                <TextInput 
                   placeholder="Enter your Username" 
                   value={this.state.text}/>
                <Button 
                title="Submit" 
                onPress={this.handleChangeText} />
            </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `handleChangeText` function should be used in `TextInput` [`onChangeText`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onchangetext) prop so that you can update the state with the correct value.

Change your code like below;

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {TextInput , Button , View } from 'react-native';

export default class Profile extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
      this.state = {
        text:''
      }
    }
  handleChangeText = (typedText) => {
    this.setState({text:typedText}, () => {
      console.log(this.state.text);
    });
  }
  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    // do something after submit
  }
  render() {
    return (
            <View> 
                <TextInput 
                   placeholder="Enter your Username" 
                   onChangeText={this.handleChangeText}
                   value={this.state.text}/>
                <Button 
                title="Submit" 
                onPress={this.handleSubmit} />
            </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

**PS:** `this.setState` is a async function so you need to use callback to read state values right after like shown above code.

Comment: Thank you, I'm now able to print the value onClicking Submit. But I'm getting warning as in the screenshot "Invalid prop `value` of type `object` supplied to `TextInput`, expected `string`."

Comment: After Editing handleSubmit , warning issue also fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing to the TextInput code to this (you're missing **onChangeText**):

```
<TextInput placeholder={'Enter your Username'}
           onChangeText={this.handleChangeText}
           value={this.state.text} />
```

Btw, setState wouldn't change the value immediately. So putting the console.log right after this.setState() probably wouldn't show the correct value.

Answer (score 3):

Your `handleChangeText` should be associated with `<TextInput>`, not with `<Button>`. You need to pass `change handler` in `onChangeText` attribute. Please try as follows.

```
<TextInput 
  onChangeText={this.handleChangeText} 
  placeholder="Enter your Username" 
  value={this.state.text}
/>
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

Your TextInput handels the changes of your Text.

```
handleChangeText(text) {
  this.setState(text); // this is async
  console.log(this.state.text) // could be the old state 
}

<TextInput 
placeholder="Enter your Username" 
value={this.state.text}
onChangeText={(text) => this.handleChangeText(text)}
/>
```

You can find more about react-native's TextInputs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html)